# Search results - Show custom fields

Tags: 7, search

Is it possible to change the output created with the Search module? I want to show custom fields, and I want to hide the description, user and date...

Comment: +1 Good question, what I need to do too, I've provided some comments as to the accepted answer as to the detail that worked for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can use [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module. A sub-module Display Suite Search allows you to change the way nodes are displayed for search results.
2. You can use `template_preprocess_search_result()` together with a copy of `modules/search/search-result.tpl.php` in your theme. Read thoroughly the comments in the `search-result.tpl.php` as they will help you understand what is going on and what is available to you.
   You can define variables this way: `$variables['your_value'] = $variables['result']['node']->field_sample[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];` and use it in the .tpl file like this: `print $your_value;`.

Comment: Thanks for this straightforward answer! I'll take a look at this right away!

Comment: I have all fields available in template_preprocess_search_result(), how do I use them in the .tpl file? Make a global variable? It's working that way, but is that the good way to do things like this?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks mate, I loved Drupal before, and I'm loving it more and more, and a bit of the honour goes to you ;)

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I helped.

Comment: +1 Great answer, thanks. Though it does seem that the way to access the field value can vary, the specific code above didn't work for me, though the general overall advice is good, what actually worked for me was, e.g.:   `$node = node_load( $vars['result']['node']->entity_id ); $description = ""; if ( isset( $node )) {
$description = $node->field_description['und'][0]['value']; }` using `dpm();` or a xdebug-based debugger to (which I did, Komodo IDE) to inspect the variables can confirm what Drupal is using at the time, so you that you can code accordingly.