# Search results: order & group by custom field

Tags: 7, entities, search

I customized the display of my search results so I can show custom fields in the search results ([other question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48175/search-results-show-custom-fields)).

I have a custom field ('Department'). I want to show the search results grouped and ordered by that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer... hook_preprocess_search_results is exactly what I need.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_search_results(&$variables) {
    $variables['search_results'] = '';
    $output_results = '';
    $output = '';

    // loop through results, group by department
    $departments = array();
    foreach ($variables['results'] as $result) {
            $departments[$result['node']->field_department[$result['node']->language][0]['value']][] = $result;
    }
    ksort($departments);

    foreach ($departments as $department => $departmentResults) {
        $value = "";
        foreach ($departmentResults as $key => $result) {
            $value .= theme('search_result', array('result' => $result, 'module' => $variables['module']));
        }

        $output_results .=  '<div id="tabs"><h3>' . $department . '</h3>';
        $output_results .=  $value;
        $output_results .=  '</div>';
    }

    $output .= '</ul>';
    $output .= $output_results;
    $output .= '</div>';

    $variables['search_results'] = $output;
}
```