# Drupal Search Result Sorting in Desc order

Tags: search

I am trying to change my Drupal site's search results. Currently it's showing the default search results by node "Updated or Changed" but i want to change it to node "Created or Published" into Descending ORDER. So all the search results will be  ORDER BY CREATED or PUBLISHED. I have looked at many files but couldn't have any success.

Which files do i have to modify and what code?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar questions [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48296/search-results-order-group-by-custom-field/48298#48298)

Use hook_preprocess_search_results and set your criteria there.

Here's the .module file you can use, this sort nodes by their creation time with a descending order. You need to create a .info file to make the module work, also remember to replace [MODULE_NAME] with your own module's name. This is not perfect but at least gives you the data in the order you want.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implement hook_preprocess_search_results()
 */
function [MODULE_NAME]_preprocess_search_results(&$vars) {
        $results = $vars['results'];// via dsm (Devel module), we can see node creation time is available under the 'results' array
        usort($results, function($v1, $v2) {
          return $v2['node']->created - $v1['node']->created; // sort by created time, DESC order
        });
        $value = '';
        $output = '';
        $output_results = array();
        foreach($results as $item) {
          $value .= theme('search_result', array('result' => $item, 'module' => $vars['module']));
          $output_results[] = $value;
          $value = '';
        } // store all results into an array
        #dsm($output_results);
        $output = implode(" ", $output_results)."<br>"; // convert array to string
        $vars['search_results'] = $output;
        #dsm($vars);
}
```

.info file:

```
name = Search Desc
description = sort default search by creation date in DESC order
core = 7.x
```

search.tpl.php file, you need to copy this file from modules/search/search-result.tpl.php and put it under your theme dir, do not modify the original.

```
<?php
$info_split['date'] = date('m/d/Y - H:i', $result['node']->created);// replace update time with created time
?>
<li class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <h3 class="title"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
    <a href="<?php print $url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
  </h3>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
  <div class="search-snippet-info">
    <?php if ($snippet): ?>
      <p class="search-snippet"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>><?php print $snippet; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($info_split): ?>
      <p class="search-info"><?php print $info_split['user'].' '.$info_split['date']; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</li>
```

**Update:**
Given Drupal's default search ranking criteria (by content relevance), an additional hook is needed inside the .module file for OP's question. After adding this, you need to go to /admin/config/search/settings and set the Influence for the 'Node Creation Date' field at the bottom of the page, re-index, and run cron.

```
/**
 * Implement hook_ranking()
 */
function [MODULE_NAME]_ranking() {
  return array(
    'node_created_date' => array(
      'title' => t('Node Creation Date'),
      'score' => 'n.created',
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. So how can i change my search.api.php etc file to take effects on search results to display created  and order by desc sort, can you please post the code for that if you already have so i can put in my file and it runs?
It's Drupal 7.

Comment: You should not edit any files inside Drupal core. Instead let's go with a custom module and run our hook function there. I'll update the answer when I get a chance to write the code...Thanks.

Comment: Hey! 
Thanks for the code. I'm sorry i'm asking so many questions. 
So i have created the searchdesc.info & searchdesc.module files in "site/modules/search", pasted your code in searchdesc.module file and changed the function name to "searchdesc_preprocess_search_results" but what should be in the searchdesc.info file?

Comment: Okay so for custom modules, you need to save them inside docroot/sites/all/modues/custom/searchdesc/ Could you try this and see if it's working? Don't forget to enable it :) Edited answer with .info file content too.

Comment: Nope :(, it did not work. The module is enabled now, in the docroot/sites/all/modues/custom/searchdesc/ path.

Comment: Interesting. Could you uncomment the last dsm (if you have Devel module enabled, otherwise use var_dump instead) and clear all cache? And let me know what happens?

Comment: var_dump showed up on search page with array including bunch of fields.

Comment: Can I take a look at your search page please? Would be helpful if you can share a test user account too.

Comment: Did the search order change at all after you enable the module? Also could you try update an older node to see if it keeps its position? I did see an issue when I searched for 'news' and the 2nd one has a smaller time stamp than the 3rd one.

Comment: So now i updated the older nodes but they are on their own positions. Doesn't affect the result. So it means that we got some progress :). Otherwise the updated node would come to the top in the search results.

Comment: Any Thoughts bout the issue?

Comment: I can't really tell why at this point with my permission... Does it sort correctly if you create new nodes instead of existing ones? Could you please test that? Because there might be something else in the current nodes that break it (different data structure, etc.)

Comment: How can i also print the date of the created node so i can test the results? 
The current printing date in search result is from search-result.tpl.php.

Really appreciate you help :)!

Comment: @Naqeeb was the previous question solved? Just curious.

Comment: I think it was but the dates are confusing me, even if i look inside the page. That's why if i print the created date then I can be 100% sure.

Comment: Do you know, how to print the date of the function("hook_preprocess_search_results") you created with the search results?

Comment: @Naqeeb am afk right now but the basic idea is you create a new variable (created time) and add it to the $vars array inside the preprocess function. And then you can call that new variable from search-result.tpl.php

Comment: @Naqeeb did you figure it out?

Comment: Nope :(, can you help?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54577/discussion-on-answer-by-cchen-drupal-search-result-sorting-in-desc-order).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the hook_preprocess_search_results solution you could also use the search_api in combination with the views module as it will allow you to customize your search results much easier.

- Download [search_api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) [search_api_db](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_db) [entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) [ctools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools)
- Enable Search API, Search views, Database search, Entity API, Views,Views UI,Ctools
- Go to *admin/config/search/search_api/add_server* fill in some server name and choose Database service as Service class
- Go to *admin/config/search/search_api/index/default_node_index* and press **Queue all items** for reindexing and then **Index now**
- Enable highlighting at *admin/config/search/search_api/index/default_node_index/workflow*
- Reindex again
- Create a page view of **Default Node Index** - Create a page - display format: **unformatted list** of **Rendered Entity**
- Add a sort filter of **Indexed Node: Date created (desc)**

**Credits:**
https://www.webwash.net/intro-to-search-api-part-1-how-to-create-search-pages/

Comment: Isn't there any way to modify Drupal Search code to show the search results in ORDER BY created not updated?

Comment: Yes but you have to use @cchen option. This is just an alternative way of doing it.

Comment: I need direction for that, which file and what code inside, so i can paste in there and it works. Do you have any example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved sorting by creation date by using the **[hook_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_query_alter/7.x)** function in a custom module. Following [blog post](https://oswol.com/blog/site-building/gotcha-altering-search-queries-drupal-7) let me in the correct direction.

```
<?php
**
 * Implements hook_query_alter().
 *
 * @param QueryAlterableInterface $query
 */
function MY_CUSTOM_MODULE_query_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
 // Alter the core node search query to sort by creation date.
 $is_search = $is_node_search = FALSE;
 $node_alias = FALSE;
 foreach ($query->getTables() as $table) {
   if ($table['table'] == 'search_index') {
     $is_search = TRUE;
   }
   if ($table['table'] == 'node') {
     $node_alias = $table['alias'];
     $is_node_search = TRUE;
   }
 }

 if ($is_search && $is_node_search) {
   $query->orderBy('created', 'DESC');
 }
}
```